# convert IP multicast to ethernet multicast address

Tags: networking, multicast, ethernet

Can someone explain how does one map IP multicast address to ethernet multicast address? 
I know for ethernet few addresses are reserved but dont know which ones

Answer (score 1):

Basically you take last 23 bits of IPv4 and add 01:00:5E at the beginning of the multicast MAC, for example:

```
ip = 224.1.2.3
mac = 0x01005e000000 + ip & 0x7FFFFF
```

> IPv4 multicast packets are delivered using the Ethernet MAC address range 01:00:5e:00:00:00–01:00:5e:7f:ff:ff (with an OUI owned by the IANA). This range has 23 bits of available address space. The first octet (01) includes the broadcast/multicast bit. The lower 23 bits of the 28-bit multicast IP address are mapped into the 23 bits of available Ethernet address space. This means that there is ambiguity in delivering packets. If two hosts on the same subnet each subscribe to a different multicast group whose address differs only in the first 5 bits, Ethernet packets for both multicast groups will be delivered to both hosts, requiring the network software in the hosts to discard the unrequired packets.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast) or [RFC 1112](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1112.txt)

Answer (score 0):

To convert an IP multicast address to a 48-bit MAC multicast address you need to understand how the 48-bit MAC multicast address came about.

To get a 48-bit MAC address OUI (24 bits, leaving 24 bits for individual addresses) registered with the IEEE used to cost $1000, which was a *lot* of money in those days. The guy experimenting with multicast couldn't afford it, so he went in with someone else to buy the OUI, and they split it, each getting 23 bits of addressing in the OUI.

An IPv4 multicast address has 28 bits of addressing (`224.0.0.0/4`, so `32-4=28`). You must somehow map the 28 bits of IPv4 addressing into 23 bits of MAC addressing. That means there are 32 times (`28-23=5` and `2^5=32`) as many IPv4 multicast addresses as there are 48-bit MAC multicast addresses. Each 48-bit MAC multicast address will map to 32 different IPv4 multicast addresses.

The mapping from an IPv4 multicast address to a 48-bit MAC multicast address is pretty simple. Just take the 48-bit MAC multicast OUI of `01-00-5E`, append a zero bit, and append the low-order 23 bits of the IPv4 multicast address. That creates the 48-bit MAC multicast address from an IPv4 multicast address.

The reverse mapping is more complex, and it is inexact since each 48-bit MAC multicast address actually represents 32 different IPv4 multicast addresses. You can only recover the last 23 bits of the IPv4 multicast address from the 48-bit MAC multicast address.